# Get starting (and ending) page of an MS Word paragraph using python-docx

Tags: python, pdf, python-docx

I'm automating the creation of an MS Word document.  When it's complete, I need to be able to save it as a PDF and insert some other/external PDF pages into the PDF version of the Word document.  To do this I was planning on leaving markers (e.g. "[pdfGoesHere]") in the Word document on their own pages.

To insert/replace the new PDF pages, I need to know what pages the markers are on.  Does python-docx have a way to determine what page number a paragraph starts (and ends) on?  I've read through the [python-docx documentation](http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) and there doesn't seem to be anything for this.  I know I can cycle through all of the paragraphs and find the paragraph(s) I'm interested in, but I can't find a deterministic way to get the paragraph's page number.

Is there a way to do this I have overlooked?  If not are there other suggestions for how to accomplish the main goal of inserting PDF pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciate the feedback given by @scanny.  Since there isn't a way to do this in `python-docx`, and I'm turning the document into a PDF anyway, I decided to use `pdfminer` to get the page numbers after the Word document was converted into a PDF.  This code may be long, but it gets the job done

```
import re
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from cStringIO import StringIO

def xmlToLines(xml):
    text = ''.join(xml)
    return text.split('\n')

#Convert a PDF found at the 'path' and turns it into XML lines
#path is the full path directory to the PDF file you're reading from 
def convert_pdf_to_xml(path):
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = StringIO()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = XMLConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)
    fp = file(path, 'rb')
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    password = ""
    maxpages = 0
    caching = True
    pagenos=set()

    print 'Converting following file from PDF to XML: \n - ' + str(path)
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages, password=password,caching=caching, check_extractable=True):
        interpreter.process_page(page)

    text = retstr.getvalue()
    lines = xmlToLines(text)

    #Close out pdf and I/O's
    fp.close()
    device.close()
    retstr.close()

    return lines

#returns a list of every page number where the field marker is found in the PDF
def getPagesWithField(wordPdfPath, field):
    lines = convert_pdf_to_xml(wordPdfPath)
    page_regex = r'page id="[0-9]*"'
    t_regex = r'<text font='
    pagesFound = []
    text = ''
    field = field.replace('<','&').replace('>','&')
    for i in range(len(lines)):
        #If it's a new page line, increment to the new page
        if len(re.findall(page_regex, lines[i])) > 0:
            page = int(re.findall(r'[0-9]{1,}', lines[i])[0])
            #print 'page: ' + str(page)
        #If it's the end of a line
        elif lines[i] == '<text>':
            #print "Text: " + text
            #check if the collected text is the field you're looking for 
            if field in text:
                pagesFound.append(page)
            text = ''
        #If it's a line with a text character, add it to text
        elif len(re.findall(t_regex, lines[i])) > 0:
            text = str(text + re.findall(r'>[^\r\n]*</text>',lines[i])[0][1])

    pagesFound = list(set(pagesFound))
    pagesFound.sort()       
    return pagesFound
```

After this, `PyPDF2` can be used for simple PDF page insertion/merging

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is No. Page numbers are determined at rendering time and are device dependent because of things like available fonts.

This answer has more of the details:
[Page number python-docx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36193159/page-number-python-docx)

Comment: Do any options open up to me if I have placed the markers on a page all by themselves using page breaks? Or, will the issues with font renderings, etc. still make that problematic?

Comment: There's no way to get page numbers from `python-docx` itself. I suppose if you placed manual page breaks in the document where you could be sure no page would overflow, you could count them up yourself. But if your content is variable, that's likely to be problematic.