# python win32api for Mac

Tags: python, pywin32

I have been trying to perform some advanced word document manipulation with **python-docx**, but [I was advised to use Microsoft office API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54371915/how-to-know-when-a-new-paragraph-in-python-docx-causes-a-new-page/54372112#54372112).

The problem is that I can't install `win32api` from [pywin32 home page](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/) because I get the following error:

```
(IntellibookVenv) MacBook-Pro-de-Hugo:Intellibook hugovillalobos$ pip install pywin32
Collecting pywin32
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pywin32
```

I don't know wether I get the error because there is not **win32api** version for Mac, or wether I am doing something wrongly.

Comment: `win32api` is just a wrapper around the Windows low-level win32 API, there is no chance of running that on Mac without some sort of OS emulator or VM.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

pywin32 is:

> Python extensions for Microsoft Windows Provides access to much of the
>   Win32 API, the ability to create and use COM objects, and the
>   Pythonwin environment.

which essentially means an interface for Python to access the native Windows API. Obviously this means to use it on Windows exclusively (I tried, doesn't event work under cygwin, so don't even think about Mac)