# How do install pywin32 on MAC OS

Tags: macos, installation, pywin32

i get the following error

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.1; however, version 20.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/Users/abc/Documents/Python /pycharmtest2/venv/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python win32api for Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54372616/python-win32api-for-mac)

Comment: Create a virtual machine with *Win* and install on that one :p

Answer (score 2):

% pip install pywin32
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32

it is used for only windows

Answer (score 1):

pywin32 is a wrapper for Windows API calls, so you can't use it on MacOS