# Microsoft Word Api for Mac

Tags: python, ms-word

I want to make some advanced manipulation of Word Documents, so [I got advised to use **win32api** instead of **python-docx**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54371915/how-to-know-when-a-new-paragraph-in-python-docx-causes-a-new-page/54372112#54372112), but it came out that [there is not **wind32api** for Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54372616/python-win32api-for-mac/54372734#54372734), so this is not possible.

Anyway, I have **Microsoft Office** installed and running on my Mac, so I hope there must be some Microsoft Word native api for Mac I can use, but I can't find any reference.

I'll appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

It's called Word VBA (Visual Basic for Applications). It's part of the default installation and the common term is for such code is "macros". Which is a bit simplified - VBA can perform very complex tasks.

What you describe in the question to which you link (knowing on which page data is located) can be done using Word VBA *but*

- there is no event that triggers when Word generates a new page due to page content "overflowing"
- it's important to realize that when a document is opened in another configuration (different machine, different printer, different printer driver...) it *may* not lay-out exactly the same - page and line breaks might be positioned differently.
- How Word controls page layout (whether a cell's content or all the lines in a paragraph must stay together on a page) can be controlled through formatting commands. It would be advisable to learn about these (end-user venue!) before proceding with generating documents.
- Use styles, not direct formatting, for generating Word document content.