# python-docx : How to printout the page number and the total page of the document?

Tags: python, docx

I'm generating a .docx document and I want to add the page number and the sum of the page in the header section.
Like in this image (yellow background):
[image]

How can I do that? Thank you very much

Comment: Check this [doc](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/analysis/features/header.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately page breaks are not inserted by the .doxc file but by the rendering engine so you can't accurately get page counts. However people have asked this before and you might be able to use a script to estimate
[Page number python-docx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36193159/page-number-python-docx)